# Is there a way to get the String value of an HttpEntity when EntityUtils.toString() returns an exception?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I keep running into this situation where I get back a bad HTTP response (like a 400) but cannot look at the HttpEntity in the HttpResponse object.  When I step through with the debugger, I can see that the entity has content (length > 0) and I can even look at the content, but all I see is an array of numbers (ASCII codes I guess?) which isn't helpful.  I'll call EntityUtils.toString() on the entity, but I get back an exception -- either an IOException, or some kind of "object is in an invalid state" exception.  This is really frustrating!  Is there any way to get at this content in a human-readable form?

Here is my code :

```
    protected JSONObject makeRequest(HttpRequestBase request) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException, WebRequestBadStatusException {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
        request.addHeader("X-PrettyPrint", "1");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300) {
            throw new WebRequestBadStatusException(statusCode);
        }

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            return new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

See where I throw the exception?  What I'd like to do is suck out the content of the HttpEntity and put it in the exception.

Comment: If stringizing fails, you could always get the raw bytes with `EntityUtils.toByteArray()` and produce a hex dump of those bytes yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that.  Know of any utilities that'll take the [100, 21, 45, 22] type of output we get from the debugger and turn that into something human-readable?

Comment: Try the String constructor: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.lang.String)

Answer (score 46):

Appache has already provided a Util class for that called [EntityUtils](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html).

```
String responseXml = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

Comment: Which is the one throwing the exception. Read the question.

Answer (score 22):

Here's some code to view the entity as a string (given that your request contentType is html or similar):

```
   String inputLine ;
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
 try {
       while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
              System.out.println(inputLine);
       }
       br.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

To enable a human readable form you can convert HttpEntity to string with UTF-8 code

```
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8")
```

This will give you Response parameters in json form like:

> { "error": {  "errors": [   {    "domain": "global",    "reason": "forbidden",    "message": "Forbidden"   }  ],  "code": 403,  "message": "Forbidden" }}

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: This is the code that throws the exception the OP is trying to solve. Do read the question before answering.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want to convert your DTO to String format then you can use ObjectMapper. Please find the following example if it helpful.

```
public static String getObjectAsString(Object object) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR: An entity can only be read once**

The problem is that an entity can only be read once. If you read it twice, you'll get these invalid state errors. You should use `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` but only once on the entity.

This is also why you have issues debugging this code. When you debug and inspect the entity, the debugger is reading the entity. If you then continue, the code will fail to read because the entity has already been read.

The reason this happens is because as a memory / runtime / garbage optimisation, the HTTP framework is reading data straight off the network to avoid caching it in memory first. If you want to read it multiple times, you need to read it from the entity (off the network), into main memory (a string variable or whatever) and then read that multiple times.